# Why MYSQL column values gets modified/deleted issue?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am building a `React Native`app with `MYSQL` as the dabase and I am using `Sequelize`ORM on `Node.js`. The problem is that I have a table called `Like` and there is a column field called `userId` and I simply store the ID of the users there. But the `userId` field gets cleared randomly. Like when I am restarting the database, or when there is an error and I need to restart the database or I am restarting the `Android Emulator`.

Here is how it looks:

```
CreateLikeModel.init({
id:{
type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true,
allowNull: false,
},

userId:{
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true
},
food_Name:{
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
},
food_id:{
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
}
```

},

And this is part of the function that saves the `user Id` when the user carry's out a like functionality:

```
 const user = await CreateCustomer.findOne({where: {id: req.user.id}});
  const likeObj ={
        user_Id:  user?.dataValues?.id?.toString(),
        food_Name: food?.dataValues?.food_Name,
        food_id: food.dataValues.id as number
       }
    //check if this user has liked this food
    const checkUser = checkLike.find((single)=> single?.dataValues.userId == 
    user.dataValues.id);
 
   if(checkUser){
      const getLike = await CreateLikeModel.findOne({where: {food_Name: 
      food.dataValues.food_Name, userId: user?.dataValues.id}});
        await getLike?.destroy();//delete the like from the record if the user already liked;
      
      return res.status(200).json('unliked');

    }
    
    await CreateLikeModel.create({...likeObj});
      return res.status(200).json('liked');
```

And I connected to the database like this:

```
sequelizeDB.sync({alter: true}).then(()=>{

console.log('connected to datatbase')
 })
```

I tried the save the `userId` as a string because it was a number before. Initially, when I used number, it usually reset the `userId` values to `0`.
It still didn't solve the problem.

This was not happening before when I was using `user_name` instead of `userId`. What could be causing the issue? For now, I usually manually input the values back in the database when they get deleted.

Comment: "Randomly" sounds like a race condition to me.

Comment: What does that mean ?

Comment: You have two operations that run at the same time, and one interferes with the other, or they don't run in the order you think they do.

Comment: You see that sample code I showed you is the only time that action is created. Nothing more.

Comment: I think you're missing something else that is happening as fields to not randomly reset themselves.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am suspecting my co-worker. I think she has not updated her source code to mine which is making her field to reset mine.

Comment: First you need to check either a user exists in DB and return 404 or somthing like this if a user does not exists and don't proceed further in this case. Second, you can access field of a model directly without `dataValues`

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `likeObj`, which you are using as the creation attributes for your like object, you have your User ID field as snake case `user_Id`, which in your model, I see it in camelCase `userId`.

I suspect this is the root of why it isn't populating the data correctly, however keep in mind that `.sync({ alter: true })` can be a destructive operation, as state in the [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#synchronization-in-production).